# How can I access the templates outside of the package?

Tags: go

I have setup a simple website based off of [this structure](https://github.com/jadekler/git-go-websiteskeleton). I run main.go and everything works fine. I'd like to be able to use this webapp in another package, say "github.com/my/package". I copied "main.go" to the "github.com/my/package" directory and run it but then get:

```
"panic: open templates/user/view.html: no such file or directory"
```

What is the recommended way to modify the path to the template file in [this file, for instance,](https://github.com/jadekler/git-go-websiteskeleton/blob/master/app/user/view.go) so that I can access the templates? I can think of two solutions:

1. Hardcode an absolute path in view.go to the template file.
2. Have a global variable in view.go then figure out where the template files are in relation to the new main.go file & set the variable to that path.

The first will obviously break if someone else were to try to use the package. The second option is a bit convoluted b/c you need to find the path to main then work your way through & figure out where the templates are...seems very convoluted.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could look at [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata). It makes external files, like templates, as part of the binary. Although it's not a great solution if you want to be able to change the templates without recompiling

Comment: @Momer: It just seems weird to me that the templates are relative to wherever your "main.go" file is...seems like the templates s/b relative to the package so that things don't break.

Answer (score 0):

If there is functionality meant to be used as a package/reused elsewhere, then the idiomatic way to do this is to move that functionality into a package - typically in the pkg directory.

Obligatory camlistore example is at https://github.com/camlistore/camlistore/tree/master/pkg

Another resource for how to do this is the ['12 golang best practices'](https://talks.golang.org/2013/bestpractices.slide#18) talk

Comment: I don't see how moving stuff in the pkg directory would change anything